# Controller - check/ping external dependencies

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, monitoring, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-signalr

I have a `.NET Core 3 Web API` that has some external dependencies like `Azure SignalR` and `Azure CosmosDb`. I have create a Monitoring Controller which I want to check if the service is healthy by for example pinging those two dependencies.

I haven't found any documentation about how to do this. I know that for example, for `Table Storage` I can call a method "*If table exists*" so if it returns true, I know the service can communicate with that dependency.

There is a way to call those dependencies?

PS: I don't want to use 3rd party packages to perform this, I want to know if those services provide this kind of methods.

Comment: Which services exactly? Have you looked at asp.net core healthchecks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that for example, for Table Storage I can call a method "If table exists" so if it returns true, I know the service can communicate with that dependency.
>
> There is a way to call those dependencies?

If you'd like to achieve same for Azure SignalR and Azure CosmosDb, you can try:

1) To check Azure SignalR service, can use [management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/signalr/signalr/get) to get details of Azure SignalR service.

2) To check Azure CosmosDb, can use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-database) to check if the database you want is existing.

Comment: Yes but I was looking something that those sdk can give me. About the 2 point, I have archive same with the sdk. I look for databases and check if mine exists in my subscription.

Comment: Do you want to achieve it using C# SDK? You can try to use [Azure Management Libraries](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net).